# Запись в переменную класса

Tags: python, ооп

Создал класс и метод

```
class Knight:
    def __init__(self, chess_board: list[list[bool]]):
        self.chess_board = chess_board

    def commandStepTo(self, x: int, y: int) -> bool:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.chess_board[x][y] = True
        print(x, y)
```

Далее создаю экземпляр класса:

```
knight = Knight([[False]*8]*8)
```

Проверяю:

```
knight.chess_board
```

output

```
[[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
```

Далее использую метод

```
knight.commandStepTo(1,2)
```

Проверяю, и у меня выводит следующее

```
[[False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]]
```

Почему у меня так записывает? Я ожидаю, что запишется только в ячейку `[1][2]`, а не во весь столбец.

Comment: про это сто раз везде написано: []*3 создает три ссылки на один и тот же объект

Comment: `knight = Knight([[False for r in range(8)] for c in range(8)])`

Comment: @S.Nick покороче, хотя чуть менее понятно, конечно... `[([False]*8)[:] for _ in range(8)]`